# Disable JavaScript in Chrome Beta via CLI on Linux

Tags: linux, javascript, command-line-arguments, google-chrome-beta

I want to launch google-chrome-beta on linux for a local html file with JavaScript disabled for all pages. I have tried the mentioned -disable-javascript option and this does not work. Anybody have a solution for this?

My usecase is for offline documentation that I scraped which I want to have the JS disabled so it does not go awry once pages load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current versions of Chrome no longer support the --disable-javascript cli option. The argument is that there is now a way to do this in the GUI so it should not be needed in the CLI options.

It was discussed to be removed back in 2010 and was formally removed some time after. Here is the change which removed the option [content_switches.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/6c5c38467301a9d56a12829452b1e823dce37728)

The work around options are to:

1. Use another browser like Tor Browser which has no JS by default
2. Create a second profile that has JS disabled:

   - This is a bit of a pain so I did not bother.

Comment: In Tor Browser 6.5.1 (based on Mozilla Firefox 45.8.0), Javascript is enabled, by default.

Answer (score 2):

on linux the parameters begin with 2 minuses

> chrome --disable-javascript

**UPDATE**: this doesn't work with the latest chrome beta, sorry.

Comment: Have you tried this on chrome beta on linux? If so, what chrome beta version and which linux. Not working for me on Suse and chrome beta Version 52.0.2743.75 beta (64-bit). FYI, google chrome beta executable should be google-chrome-beta which is in /usr/bin on Suse.

Comment: sorry, you're right! It's working with stable, but not with beta. I think google made some mistake.

Comment: Raised bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=638401

Comment: This is not a bug. The feature was removed from Chrome in the last year.